# Setting default image dpi using sphinx and texi2pdf

Tags: pdftex, resolution, sphinx

In [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org) project, we are using Sphinx to create our documentation as HTML and PDF. We are  having a bit of a problem with figures as they show a bit blurry in PDF. I found out that the reason is because `texi2pdf` default DPI is 72.

I would like to set it to something like 135dpi.

I have read somewhere that I should use `\pdfimageresolution` for this; I tried to use it as:

```
latex_preamble = r"""\pdfimageresolution135"""
```

in the sphinx [`conf.py`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/blob/master/source/conf.py) file, but with no results.

Can anyone explain me if this is the right direction, or what is being done wrong?